# Different outputs about saved continuations in DrRacket's definitions window and interactions window

Tags: racket

I'm new to Racket and I'm trying to use call/cc. When I put the following code in the definitions window
of DrRacket, run it, and type `(saved-k 0)` in the interactions window, I get two of `3` printed.

```
#lang racket ; the definitions window

(define saved-k #f)

(define (f)
  (+ 1
     (call/cc (λ (k) (set! saved-k k) 0))))

(+ 1 (+ 1 (f)))
```

```
; the interactions window
3
> (saved-k 0)
3
3
```

My understanding is that the saved continuation should be `(+ 1 (+ 1 (+ 1 ?)))`
where `?` is the hole. Why are there two results printed?

When I try all of those things in the interactions window, everything looks normal.

```
; the interactions window
> (define saved-k #f)
> (define (f)
    (+ 1
       (call/cc (λ (k) (set! saved-k k) 0))))
> (+ 1 (+ 1 (f)))
3
> (saved-k 0)
3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Racket prints values at the top level. For example, running

```
#lang racket
1
2
```

will print `1` and `2`.

How is this done? Well, when the program is run, it expands the code to something like:

```
(module test racket
  (#%module-begin
   (#%app call-with-values (lambda () '1) print-values)
   (#%app call-with-values (lambda () '2) print-values)))
```

where `print-values` is responsible for the printing.

What happened in your program is that when the continuation is captured, it includes the `print-values` frame. That's why when you invoke the continuation, you see the double printing. One from `print-values`. Another from the evaluation result.

But when you try them all in the interactive window, there's no `print-values`, so there's no double printing.